# Hide and show keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have two screens in my flutter app, in the first screen, i use this code for hide the keyboard:

`SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');`

And that works fine, but when i navigate to next screen, the keyboards is still hiding, even when i called this code,that is supposed to do the opposite of the previous one:

`SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');`

Is there another way to recover the keyboard on the second screen?

Comment: Use `autoFocus:true` in your respective `TextField` in second screen.

Comment: I already set the autofocus, but the keyboard is automatically hidden

Comment: use GestureDetactor single tap and do manage FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()); that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the soft keyboard, you can invoke `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()`

You can wrap the body's child with the `GestureDetector` to hide the keyboard when any surface has been tapped.

```dart
GestureDetector(
  /// Hide keyboard when on tapping the surface
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
  child: Container(
    ...
  ),
)
```

To display the soft keyboard, it should automatically appear when TextFormField/TextField has been tapped for input. You can set `autoFocus:true` to one of the `TextField` to automatically display the keyboard.